# Programmatically creating sub tasks via the attask API

Tags: attask

I'd like to add a subtask to an existing task, using the attask api.  I can add a task to a project, using a POST method and the following:

`/attask/api/task?name=Created Task&projectID=553f...&sessionID=b529...`

I tried to create a sub task, using a post method and the following:

`/attask/api/task?name=Created Sub Task&taskID=5540...&sessionID=b529...`

I get an error that the APIModel V2_0 does not support the field taskID.

I can create sub tasks in the user interface, but need to do so programmatically.  The project entails synchronizing TFS tasks as sub tasks to the tasks created in AtTask. The tasks from AtTask will become the backlog stories in TFS.  I suggested an alternative solution, following the attask suggested portfolio (Business Unit), program (tfs: project / scrum team), project (tfs: story), task (tfs: task) paradigm, but that suggestion hasn't gotten traction.

Does the API support the creation of sub tasks?  If so, can you provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper syntax for adding a subtask is parentID not taskID so the following should work

```
 POST   /attask/api/task?name=Created Sub Task&projectID=54c7...&parentID=55413...&sessionID=2gi...
```

Comment: Awesome, worked like a champ.  Thanks!  Is there a better / another set of documentation that details the fields available through the api?  The link on the ATTask dev page links back to the dev page.

Comment: https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/api-explorer/ should have all the fields you can use with the api